# c++ strange execution logic

Tags: c++, execution

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "How many turns do you want to do?" << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::string turnsDefined;
    std::cin >> turnsDefined;
    std::cout << turnsDefined;
    bool hasPassed = false;
    int objectSize;
    for(char c : turnsDefined){
        objectSize++;
    }
    std::cout << objectSize;
    while(hasPassed != true){
        for(char c : turnsDefined){
            if(isdigit(c) != true){
                hasPassed = false;
                break;  
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Successfully passed all if conditions.";
    return 0;
}
```

So, all that this short program is doing, is that it's getting a users input, tests if it contains any letters, and then sets a bool to either false or true (I know that that part won't work, but that's not what I'm asking for). My problem with this is: As soon as I input something, I'm expecting it to return it right back (`std::cin >> turnsDefined; "NEWLINE" std::cout << turnsDefined;`) however, it's just pausing and not returning anything.

Comment: You haven't initialized `objectSize`.

Comment: You never set `hasPassed` to be `true`, so your while loop won't exit. As you don't flush cout (simply by giving it a newline, or `std::endl`), it probably won't display anything.

Comment: @icabod I'm very aware that I never set hasPassed to true. But it shouldn't change anything since the loop is entered after the code.

Comment: Hint: Everyting beyond `std::cout << turnsDefined;` is inconsequential to your question. The output does not happen, even if you `while ( true );` right after that. That's probably the first thing you should have tried yourself. Your question could've been done with 8 lines of code and a single sentence. Besides, **because of this** you missed the point of icabod's (correct) answer.

Comment: `for(char c : turnsDefined){
    objectSize++;
}` What about `int objectSize = turnDefined.size();`? :)

Comment: @user657267 I have now. And just so you know, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @jrok Thanks for the tip. I'll be sure to change that. I'm still interested in solving my original question.

Comment: @Code0: Again, the answer is right there in icabod's comment. *You don't flush cout*.

Comment: Well, I added that now and it still doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Code0: Did you recompile? Because it sure works for me.

Comment: Okay, I now got the full program to work. Thanks (mainly) to @icabod and DevSolar.

Comment: For the record, either explicitly flushing `cout` (via `endl` or `.flush()` or whatever) _or exiting the process_ would cause the output to flush. My point was that the infinite loop stops the output from being flushed unless you explicitly do it.

Comment: @icabod: You should post an answer, so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're not getting any output is that `stdout` (as used by default by `cout`) is not getting flushed.  The `stdout` stream is buffered, and this buffer will only be flushed in certain circumstances: reaching a newline, when it is instructed to flush (for example with `cout.flush()`), or on exiting the process.

In your code you're not outputting any newlines, you're not manually flushing the buffer, and (because `hasPassed` is never set to `true`, resulting in an infinite loop) you're never exiting the process.  For these reasons, `stdout` is never being flushed, so any output is not being shown on the display.